# Lenght of a list in OCaml

Tags: ocaml

How to get a length of a longest sublist in a list? I've spend a lot of time on this, and i got no clue.

For example:

```
Function([[1;2];[1;2;3];[]])
```

returns 3

Comment: The `,` is used in tuples, not lists. Use a semi-colon to separate individuals of a list.

Comment: Thanks. Thats my typical mistake in ocaml.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even though other solutions using `fold_left` work, here's a solution that is "manually-coded":

```
let longestsublist l = 
    (let rec aux l current_max = match l with
                                 | [] -> current_max
                                 | x::xs -> aux xs (max (List.length x) current_max)              
     in aux l (-1))
```

Answer (score 4):

I'm quite rusty with OCaml but a `List.fold_left` should be enough:

```
List.fold_left (fun a b -> Pervasives.max a (List.length b)) 0 [[1;2];[1;2;3];[]]
```

I can't test the code right now and it has been a long time since I last used OCaml (version 3.XX) so syntax maybe a little different, but the approach definitely works: you pass to fold a function which takes the current maximum and the current sublist as input, it returns the maximum between the two.

Comment: Can you try do this with elementar operations? I mean without using List.fold_left and List.length ?

Comment: You'll have to define what 'elementary operations' implies. If you cannot use the List module, it begs the question since you are using Lists.

Answer (score 3):

This should work

```
 List.fold_left (fun current_max l -> max current_max (List.length l)) 0 [[1;2]; [1;2;3]; []]
```

You can try it on http://try.ocamlpro.com